# Understanding meta ethical judgement in nicomachean ethics

Tags: ethics, aristotle, metaethics

I'm reading [Nicomachean Ethics's penguin classics version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140449493) and the introduction section contains this paragraph and I'm having some trouble understanding this.

From what I've read so far I understand that meta-ethical judgement are judgements about ethical judgements. But I don't understand how "The concept of F includes the concept of G" is a meta-ethical judgement.

Is my understanding of meta-ethical judgements correct? If yes then what's the ethical judgement that the given meta-ethical judgement is judging?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is not saying that, "The concept of F includes the concept of G" is a meta-ethical judgement. Rather, you can form a meta-ethical judgement in that form by replacing F and G with "murder" and "wrongness".

The ethical judgement is: "Murder is wrong"
The meta-ethical judgement is an analysis of the ethical judgement: "The concept of murder (F) includes the concept of wrongness (G)"